# Given only the velocity vector at one given instant, what predictions can we make?

Tags: classical-mechanics

> Suppose that all we know about a motion of a particle is the velocity
> vector at a given instant and that the particle has a fixed mass. What
> can we say of the motion based only on that?

I thought that maybe we can say that the particle will keep moving for a while is a prediction we can make based only on that information. Is that correct? Are there more things we can say?

EDIT:

Conjecture: if the motion was restricted to be in a plane, given only the velocity vector at one given instant and that the particle has mass, would mean the particle will remain at a certain half-plane for some $t$ seconds after that (where $t$ can be very small), see image:

[image]

Is my conjecture correct? What if the motion is in three-dimensions?

Comment: I think the only thing you know is the instantaneous velocity and instantaneous momentum of particle.

Comment: So we know the forces acting on the particle are zero, or we don't know anything about the forces.

Comment: I suspect that what the question really wants to ask is "Restate Newton's laws of motion in the context of a particle with mass $m$, velocity $\vec v$."

Comment: @John Alexiou: In my problem, we don't know anything about the forces other than we "live" in a classical mechanics universe where they may or may not be present.

Comment: @jainemarie - I asked this to ascertain if this is a kinematics question or a dynamics question. In terms of kinematics, you study all possible motions that fit the constraints (in this case 1 point with specified velocity), and in dynamics, you study the _specific_ motion that happens due to specified forces and initial conditions. Can you clarify the question and what answer you are looking for? Also is this particle isolated, or part of a system forming a rigid body, or even a broader mechanism?

Comment: @John Alexiou: Ah, I see. So, by this classification I think it's a kinematics problem (I think!). I may need help clarifying the question. It all started when my 12-years old sister asked me what is "instantaneous velocity", and I said that for small time intervals the velocity doesn't change much, and you could consider "instantaneous velocity" as approximately constant for such small intervals, but she was not convinced by this, due to that "it could change much no matter how small the interval, and it need to be approximately constant", so I tried to know the implications of [continue]

Comment: @John Alexiou: [continued] knowing only the instantaneous velocity at one given instant. There are things like functions with derivative at only on point, but I doubt they have physical significance.

Comment: You might be able to come up with a distribution of $\Delta\vec{x}$ the particle could have moved after $\Delta t$ time, but you'd have to include things like all boundaries and forces that could be applied after $\Delta t$ for the parameter space to be sufficiently complete so as to come up with probabilities for the distribution.

Comment: @jainemarie - is it only a particle, or part of a bigger body?

Comment: @jainemarie tell your sister that instantaneous velocity is the velocity it has at any instant. But we cannot directly measure this, but instead, we measure positions on two close by time frames and get a value approximately close to the actual instantaneous velocity. At any time frame, a body has only one velocity, and there is no notion of being constant since the time factor has been removed. Variation can happen as time flows, and this is close to what Newton considered a fluxion.

Comment: @John Alexiou: I thought of it as a particle, but I guess particles don't really exist in the real world (but I see them often used as approximations, like the Earth and the Sun as particles). Btw, in this problem it's like Nuclear Hoagie said in his answer: "velocity is continuous". I think this is important.

Comment: @John Alexiou: I will! Let's see if she will be satisfied, she wants to become a philosopher, haha!

Comment: @jainemarie Since this is not a textbook problem, I'd note that this doesn't have to be a  mechanics problem. If you re-interpret the question as a *Bayesian statistics problem*, we may know a great deal about the *most probable* behavior of particles with masses similar to $m$, velocities similar to $v$. E.g. if the mass is the mass of a proton, and the velocity is close to $c$, that's strong evidence that the particle will remain at that velocity for years, because it's almost certainly a cosmic ray, and if it's a cosmic ray, it's almost certainly in deep space.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for this.TO add to @Bob D's answer, we can also find the kinetic energy of the system at that point in time. So to summarise, I think, Velocity, momentum, and kinetic energy. However, if you mean that we are given the equation of the instantaneous velocity vector, we can find a lot more, including acceleration, distance traveled in a given amount of time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know the acceleration at this time, simply the velocity and time that we are seeing the particle in, so therefore it is an estimate and subject to change. We are simply seeing it in a place in time completely frozen. We can figure out the kinetic energy of the particle at the moment as we know its mass and velocity which is all we need.

What we cannot do is figure out with certainty the acceleration, because we have to then take more snapshots to search for a pattern, if one exists and the acceleration isn't widely varying. This is the limit, unless you are absolutely sure that the velocity will not change for the rest of the particles movement, you cannot predict the velocity or destination of the particle with certainty. You can only estimate and approximate.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: We wouldn't know the position/location of the particle as well. Only velocity is given.

Comment: @Eragon_18 I fixed the error where I mention location. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Given *only* an instantaneous velocity, we cannot predict anything at all about the future position or trajectory of the particle. We could plot the trajectory if we knew what forces were acting upon it, for instance that it would travel in a straight line at a constant velocity if no forces were acting, or that it would travel in a parabolic trajectory under the influence of gravity. But without knowing anything about how the particle is accelerating, we cannot predict anything about its future position.

Suppose a car is heading east at 60km/h. In one hour, the car may be 60km to the east if it does not accelerate at all. But it may be 100km to the east if it speeds up, or only 30km to the east if it slows down, or 50km to the north if it turns, or 20km to the west if it stops and reverses direction. Given only the car's velocity at one point in time, we cannot determine the car's future position, since we don't know how the velocity is changing.

In your half-plane example, we cannot claim with certainty that the particle remains in the half-plane to the right for *any* non-zero $t$, since it's possible that the particle turns around between time $0$ and $t$.

In practice, forces and acceleration are not infinite, so velocity is continuous in real systems. This implies that a particle moving to the right will, in fact, still be moving to the right some time later, so long as the time step is small enough - the particle cannot instantaneously reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

It depends in which way the velocity vector is given.

If it is a constant, we can determine the instantaneous velocity (magnitude and direction), the linear momentum in terms of mass 'm', and kinetic energy, again in terms of m.

If it is given as a function of time 't', we can find out the position at that instant and the instantaneous acceleration.